# Event Study (Extracting Dates in SAS)

Tags: events, date, sas

I need to analyse abnormal returns for an event study on mergers and acquisitions.

** I would like to analyse abnormal returns to acquirers by using event windows. Basically I would like to extract the prices for the acquirers using -1 (the day before the announcement date), announcement date, and +1 (the day after the announcement date).**

I have two different datasets to extract information from.
The first is a dataset with all the merger and acquisition information that has the information in the following format:

```
DealNO AcquirerNO TargetNO AnnouncementDate
123    abcd       Cfgg     22/12/2010
222    qwert      cddfgf   26/12/1998
```

In addition, I have a 2nd dataset which has all the prices.

```
ISINnumber Date                      Price
abcd       21/12/2010                10
abcd       22/12/2010                11
abcd       23/12/2010                11
abcd       24/12/2010                12
qwert      20/12/1998                20
qwert      21/12/1998                20
qwert      22/12/1998                21
qwert      23/12/1998                21
qwert      24/12/1998                21
qwert      25/12/1998                22
qwert      26/12/1998                21
qwert      27/12/1998                23
```

ISIN number is the same as acquirer no, and that is the matching code.

In the end I would like to have a database something like this:

```
DealNO AcquirerNO TargetNO AnnouncementDate Acquirerprice(-1day)  Acquireeprice(0day)     Acquirerprice(+1day)
123    abcd       Cfgg     22/12/2010       10                    11                               12
222    qwert      cddfgf   26/12/1998       22                    21                               23
```

Do you know how I can get this? 
I'd prefer to use sas to run the code, but if you are familiar with any other programs that can get the data like this, please let me know.

Thank you in advance ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily with PROC SQL and joining the PRICE dataset three times.  Try this (assuming data set names of ANNOUCE and PRICE):

Warning: untested code

```
%let day='21DEC2010'd;

proc sql;
   create table RESULT as 
      select a.dealno,
             a.acquirerno,
             a.targetno,
             a.annoucementdate,
             p.price as acquirerprice_prev,
             c.price as acquirerprice_cur,
             n.price as acquirerprice_next
      from ANNOUCE a 
           left join (select * from PRICE where date = &day-1) p on a.acquirerno = p.isinumber
           left join (select * from PRICE where date = &day) c on a.acquirerno = c.isinumber
           left join (select * from PRICE where date = &day+1) n on a.acquirerno = n.isinumber
   ;
quit;
```